# WidgetKit: closure #1 getDescriptors(:completion) Crash

Tags: swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I recently released a iOS 14 WidgetKit extension that's fairly basic, works great on my devices (both in development and from TestFlight) and the simulators, however I keep seeing crashes reported in AppStoreConnect Analytics as well as the Organizer Reports (Crashes). The Crash Report states the following error:

```
WidgetKit: closure #1 in WidgetExtension Context.getDescriptors(completion:)
```

I am using the latest Xcode 12.0.1.

The only thing I can find about this error is this post on the Apple WidgetKit forum:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655776
According to this post, the error seemed to go away when updating to the non-Beta Xcode, but that is not the case for me...

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Or better, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Would you provide your code?